# WP7 Converting an ASCII String to an Image

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to convert an ASCII string to an ImageSource like so in WP7:

```
            string imageString = "%PNG image data here in ASCII";

            byte[] imageBytes = new byte[sizeOfImage];
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imageString.ToCharArray(), 0, imageString.ToCharArray().Length - 1, 
                imageBytes, 0);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

            // Convert byte[] to Image
            ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

            BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(ms);
```

But there is no Encoding.ASCII in WP7 so obviously on the "Encoding.UTF" line it fails because WP7 only has that encoding. Is there any workaround for this?

Note: the ASCII string represents a PNG file.

Comment: What kind of encoding are you using in addition to just "ASCII"? You do know that ASCII is only 7 bits, right? Why are you encoding an image as text in the first place?

Comment: "this is Unicode"; I'm confused.

Comment: Doesn't WP7 projects allow resource files or similar where you could put an actual binary copy of the PNG file instead of trying to do it like this? I'm pretty sure that ASCII "representation" of yours doesn't actually represent a real PNG file. It may look like it to you, but it won't be a valid PNG file because ASCII is only 7 bits, so you lose a lot of information in that process.

Comment: Since you've gone to great lengths to encode the file inside the source code, why not just store it as a byte array in the source instead?

Comment: I am getting a PNG string (ASCII) from a web server.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that what you really want to be doing is this:-

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);
```

However Lasse is right.  Why on earth would you want to do this?  Just add the png to the Xap as Content.  The whole becomes something like:-

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/yourfile.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Where Assets is a folder you create in your project to store such things.

Comment: Yes, unless your image information is stored in ASCII data somewhere it is much easier to just use the binary file (png, jpg, wav) as content.

Comment: I am getting a png file as an ASCII string from a web server. So Base64 really work.